# Replace IP address within a string

Tags: bash, scripts

I'd like to change the IP address in this string with some user input:

```
rmi.sceduling.service.url=rmi\://192.168.0.19\:1199/ScedulingService
```

The code should also work if there is no address:

```
rmi.sceduling.service.url=
```

It should also be portable, at least to Solaris.

The code I am using at the moment:

```
value=`grep 'rmi' application.properties \
| awk -F":" '{print $2}' \
| awk -F"\'" '{print $1}'
| cut -d '/' -f 3-5 `

sed -e "s/$value/$host_ip/g" application.properties > file.tmp \
&& mv file.tmp application.properties
```

Comment: Isn't this a question for stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portable solution that should work on both solaris and ubuntu

```
ed -s application.properties << EOF
  g/=rmi\\\\:\/\/[^\]*/s||=rmi\\\\://$host_ip|
  w
EOF
```

Why are you doing all these edits (in this and several of your other recent questions) on this application.properties file anyway? Seems to me that just writing that file from scratch would be much easier.

Comment: yea thats would be good idea to write application.properties from scratch :))),, thanks 4 your replay

Comment: thanks it work perfectly ,,,well am trying doing this because i want learn shell script ...SO much hard much fast learn...

Comment: @geirha..in terminal your script work with no any problem when i append  it in my script it always telling me unexpected end of file !!! ??

Comment: The closing `EOF` must not be indented. There is an indented variety where you do `cmd <<- EOF` in which case preceding tabs (\t) will be ignored, but regular spaces will still make it fail.

Comment: that's right i will try figure that out ....if i find something i will post the solution ..

Answer (score 2):

Here's a naïve solution:

```
sed -i -e "s#rmi\\\\://[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+#$host_ip#"
```